# How $\varphi (s)=0$ in this paper about stochastic processes?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, expected-value

$\newcommand{\Ex}{\mathbb E}$
Let $X^i, X^j, X^k$ be independent copies of a stochastic process $X$. Let $\beta:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be bounded continuous. Let $b(s, x) := \Ex[\beta(x- X_s)]$ for all $s \in [0, \infty)$ and $x \in \mathbb R$. Let
$$
\varphi (s) :=\Ex [(\beta(X^i_s - X^j_s) - b(s, X^i_s)) (\beta(X^i_s - X^k_s) - b(s, X^i_s))] \quad \forall s \in [0, \infty).
$$

Then it's mentioned in the proof of *Lemma 5.4.* of this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414998000180) that

> $\varphi (s)=0$ for all $s \in [0, \infty)$.

I decompose
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi (s) &= \Ex [\beta(X^i_s - X^j_s) \beta(X^i_s - X^k_s)] - \Ex [\beta(X^i_s - X^j_s) b(s, X^i_s)] \\
& \qquad - \Ex [\beta(X^i_s - X^k_s) b(s, X^i_s)] + \Ex [b^2(s, X^i_s)],
\end{align}
$$
but I could not see how $\varphi (s)=0$. Could you elaborate on this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read the paper, but the following may be useful to you. All equalities with conditional expectations are in the a.e. sense.

---

Let $X,Y,Z$ be real-valued random variables. Suppose $P(X \in A,Y \in B|Z)=P(X \in A|Z)P(Y \in B|Z)$ for all $A,B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. we have conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ wrt $Z$). Let $A,B,C,D \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}E[\mathbf{1}_{A \times B}(X,Z)\mathbf{1}_{C \times D}(Y,Z)|Z]&=E[\mathbf{1}_A(X)\mathbf{1}_{C}(Y)|Z]\mathbf{1}_{B}(Z)\mathbf{1}_{D}(Z)=\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_A(X)|Z]E[\mathbf{1}_{C}(Y)|Z]\mathbf{1}_{B}(Z)\mathbf{1}_{D}(Z)=\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_{A \times B}(X,Z)|Z]E[\mathbf{1}_{C \times D}(Y,Z)|Z]\end{aligned}$$
So for $C,D$ fixed we have
$$\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \{F \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2):E[\mathbf{1}_F(X,Z)\mathbf{1}_{C\times D}(Y,Z)|Z]=E[\mathbf{1}_{F}(X,Z)|Z]E[\mathbf{1}_{C \times D}(Y,Z)|Z]\}$$
The lhs is a $\pi$-system generating $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. The rhs is a $\lambda$-system. So
$$E[\mathbf{1}_F(X,Z)\mathbf{1}_{C\times D}(Y,Z)|Z]=E[\mathbf{1}_{F}(X,Z)|Z]E[\mathbf{1}_{C \times D}(Y,Z)|Z],\,\forall F \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
Since $C,D$ were arbitrary, an equivalent argument shows that
$$E[\mathbf{1}_F(X,Z)\mathbf{1}_{G}(Y,Z)|Z]=E[\mathbf{1}_{F}(X,Z)|Z]E[\mathbf{1}_{G}(Y,Z)|Z],\,\forall F,G \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
Now let $f,g$ be bounded measurable functions. A standard argument with simple functions and convergence theorems shows that
$$E[f(X,Z)g(Y,Z)|Z]=E[f(X,Z)|Z]E[g(Y,Z)|Z]$$

---

Now suppose $(X,Y)$ is independent from $Z$ and $X$ is independent from $Y$. Then for $A,B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$
$$\begin{aligned}P(X \in A,Y \in B|Z)&=P(X \in A,Y \in B)=\\
&=P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)=\\
&=P(X \in A|Z)P(Y \in B|Z)
\end{aligned}$$
so the above holds.

---

Recall that if $X$ is independent from $Z$, $Y$ is independent from $Z$ and $X \sim Y$ (i.e. they have identical distribution) then for bounded measurable $f$ we have
$$E[f(X,Z)|Z]=E[f(X,z)]|_{z=Z}=E[f(Y,z)]|_{z=Z}=E[f(Y,Z)|Z]$$
We may define $b(z):=E[f(X,z)]=E[f(Y,z)]$; note: $b(Z)=E[f(X,Z)|Z]=E[f(Y,Z)|Z]$.

---

Finally, suppose $(X,Y)$ is independent from $Z$ and $X$ is independent from $Y$ and $X \sim Y$ and $b(z):=E[f(X,z)]=E[f(Y,z)]$ for a bounded measurable $f$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}E[(f(X,Z)-b(Z))(f(Y,Z)-b(Z))]&=E[f(X,Z)f(Y,Z)]+\\
&-E[f(X,Z)b(Z)]+\\
&-E[f(Y,Z)b(Z)]+\\
&+E[b(Z)^2]=\\
&=E[E[f(X,Z)f(Y,Z)|Z]]+\\
&-E[E[f(X,Z)|Z]b(Z)]+\\
&-E[E[f(Y,Z)|Z]b(Z)]+\\
&+E[b(Z)^2]=\\
&=E[E[f(X,Z)|Z]E[f(Y,Z)|Z]]+\\
&-E[b(Z)^2]+\\
&-E[b(Z)^2]+\\
&+E[b(Z)^2]=0
\end{aligned}$$